# background-position is not coming properly

Tags: html, css

I am using an image as background in a table cell,

If I'm using `background-position: -14px bottom !important;` it is coming correctly positioning at the bottom.

But If I'm using  `background-position: -14px 0px !important;`, it is not coming at the bottom of the cell. It is placed the image in the  middle of the cell.

**What's the difference between the two?**

```
background-position: -14px bottom !important;

background-position: -14px 0px !important;
```

Do I need to use any position property to fix it (relative or absolute)?

Please advice me..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: @NoobEditor thank you.I got the answer form the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using two px-values, the first value is the horizontal position from the left and the second is the vertical from the top.

So in

```
background-position: -14px 0px !important;
```

your image should be positioned at the top and 14px the the left of the very left edge.

While in

```
background-position: -14px bottom !important;
```

your image should show at the bottom and 14px to the left of the very left edge.

Comment: thank you for the reply,then whats the px value for the bottom in the first code?

Comment: background-position:  left -14px bottom 0px !important; is the Answer